# fatal error: 'png.h' file not found — how to point r install package from source to opt/homebrew/include/png.h

Tags: r, apple-m1, install.packages

Apple M1 doesn't have `png.h` in the expected libraries for R packages to find when installing from source.

I've installed it using homebrew,

```
> brew install libpng
```

which installs `png.h` to,

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libpng/1.6.39/include/libpng16/png.h
```

with a symlink at,

```
/opt/homebrew/include/png.h
```

When I try to install the package,

```
install.packages("ggiraph", type = "source")
```

I get the error,

```
clang++ -arch arm64 -std=gnu++14 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/Rcpp/include' -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/systemfonts/include' -I/opt/R/arm64/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c raster.cpp -o raster.o
In file included from raster.cpp:4:
In file included from ./dsvg.h:7:
In file included from ./dsvg_dev.h:7:
./interactive.h:23:9: warning: 'InteractiveElements::push' hides overloaded virtual function [-Woverloaded-virtual]
  INDEX push(SVGElement* el);
        ^
./indexed.h:29:17: note: hidden overloaded virtual function 'IndexedElements::push' declared here: different number of parameters (2 vs 1)
  virtual INDEX push(SVGElement* el, const bool& add_id = true);
                ^
In file included from raster.cpp:4:
In file included from ./dsvg.h:7:
In file included from ./dsvg_dev.h:8:
./clip.h:27:9: warning: 'Clips::push' hides overloaded virtual function [-Woverloaded-virtual]
  INDEX push(SVGElement* el, const char* key = NULL);
        ^
./indexed.h:29:17: note: hidden overloaded virtual function 'IndexedElements::push' declared here: type mismatch at 2nd parameter ('const bool &' vs 'const char *')
  virtual INDEX push(SVGElement* el, const bool& add_id = true);
                ^
raster.cpp:7:10: fatal error: 'png.h' file not found
#include <png.h>
         ^~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed R from a CRAN binary rather than from sources, then you should be installing external libraries using the binaries hosted [here](https://mac.r-project.org/bin/darwin20/arm64/) rather than from Homebrew, whose binaries may not be compatible with CRAN's.  In your case, I would try:

```bash
$ curl -LO https://mac.r-project.org/bin/darwin20/arm64/libpng-1.6.38-darwin.20-arm64.tar.xz
$ sudo tar -xvf libpng-1.6.38-darwin.20-arm64.tar.xz -C /
```

That should install `libpng` under `/opt/R/arm64`, where CRAN configures R to find external libraries.  You can query the default search paths using `R CMD config`:

```bash
$ R CMD config CPPFLAGS
-I/opt/R/arm64/include
$ R CMD config LDFLAGS
-L/opt/R/arm64/lib
```

If you insist on using your Homebrew installation, then add to the default search paths by setting `PKG_CPPFLAGS` and `PKG_LIBS`:

```r
$ PKG_CPPFLAGS=-I/opt/homebrew/include R -e "install.packages(\"ggiraph\", type = \"source\")"
```